# How to obtain y-axis-labels in ggplot2?

Tags: r

I got stuck in a simple problem.

I have an easy ggplot2 and I just want to extract the y-axis-labels
Here is a reproducible Code:

```
                    library(ggplot2)

                    ### Create random Data ###

                    real_xdata <- seq(from=1,to=1000,by=1)
                    real_ydata <- runif(1000,0,100)

                    ### Create Dataframe for ggplot2 ###

                    ggplot_data <- data.frame(matrix(NA,
                    nrow = length(real_xdata),
                    ncol = 2))

                    ggplot_data$X1 <- real_xdata
                    ggplot_data$X2 <- real_ydata

                    ggplot_one <- ggplot(ggplot_data, aes(x = X1, y = X2)) +
                     geom_line() +  
                     theme_gray() 

                    print(ggplot_one)
```

In this case I would need the numbers 0, 25, 50, 75, 100

I tried stuff like

`str(ggplot_one)`

or

`str(ggplot_one$scales)`

But have no idea how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay thanks a lot,that worked. can i delete the thread or will it be deleted?

Comment: No, you don't have to delete it. See e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132600/should-i-delete-my-answer-to-a-question-thats-marked-as-a-duplicate). If someone searches for an answer and uses search terms which direct them to _your_ question (and _not_ the other Q&A), your post will be helpful in guiding them to the answer.